# How do we explain the hadith regarding the sun's relation to the throne of Allah?

Tags: allah, hadith-interpretation

Abû Dharr al-Ghifârî, is as follows:

> The Prophet (peace be upon him) said one day: “Do you know where the Sun goes when it sets?”
>
> They said: “Allah and His Messenger know best.”
>
> He said: “It goes until it arrives at its place of settlement beneath the Throne. Then it falls down in prostration and remains like that until it is said to it: ‘Arise! Go back from whence you came.’ Then it goes back and rises from its place of rising. Then it goes until it arrives at its place of settlement beneath the Throne. Then it falls down in prostration and remains like that until it is said to it: ‘Arise! Go back from whence you came.’ Then it goes back and rises from its place of rising. Then it goes without people finding anything wrong with it until it arrives at that place of settlement it has beneath the throne. Then it will be told: ‘Arise! Enter upon the morning rising from your setting place’.”
>
> Then Allah’s Messenger (peace be upon him) said: “Do you know when that will be? It will be when ‘its faith will not avail a soul which had not believed before or earned some good from its faith. [Sûrah al-An`âm: 157]’.” [Sahîh Muslim (159,205) ]

(This hadith is at [IslamToday](http://en.islamtoday.net/artshow-296-4020.htm); see also [sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/10).)

Can I get an explanation of this hadith, please?

Comment: This question seems to me a duplicate I've given an answer for this question but can't post a link to it as I'm using my mobile at the moment.