# What should be my attitude when I see conflict in science and Islam at some point?

Tags: practical-islam, science

Narrated by Abu Dhar:

> The prophet asked me at sunset,"Do you know where the sun goes(at the
>   time of sunset)? "I replied, "Allah and His Apostle know better." He
>   said,"it goes(i.e travels) till it prostrates itself underneath the
>   throne and takes the permission to rise again,and it is permitted and
>   then (a time will come when)it will be about to prostrate itself but
>   its prostration will not e accepted,and it will asked permission to go
>   on it course but it will not be permitted,but it will be orderded to
>   return whence it has come and so it will rise in the West And that is
>   the interpretation of the statement of Allah: "And the sun Runs its
>   fixed course For a term(decreed) that is the Decree of(Allah) The
>   Exalted in Might,The All-knowing."
>
>   [[Sahih Bukhari Volume 4,Book 54,Number 421]](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/10).

This is the example in which we can see the conflict between the science and Islam.

Comment: What is your question there's a gap between your question title and the content. See [ask].

Comment: This hadith has been discussed before [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/18308/isnt-this-hadith-about-sunset-unscientific) and addressed [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35688/how-do-we-explain-the-hadith-regarding-the-suns-relation-to-the-throne-of-allah)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.
**The prophet Mohammad is not between us** [not in the way we can understand in physical word] [And also we cant access Imam Mahdi (Aj)[1]]
so we cant say our understanding from Islam, is the real Islam. because we cant ask prophet and fix our mistakes!

2.
**Science is not complete**. Number of open questions in Science is too much. and every day may one scientist find something that shows previous concepts that was accepted was false.
like Einstein that showed Quantum physic. and Showed relation between material and energy! which was unbelievable 10 years before him.

3.
**Sometimes two things have no conflicts but we think there is one.**

for example looking at a cross from two Dimensional perspective shows a cross but looking in three Dimensional area may show a space between them.

the other famous example of this is the elephant in the dark room, 5 men are in the room. each one touch a different part of the elephant and says what it is! one say it is a barrel ( who touched elephants legs) the other says it is a Sweep ( who touched tails) and so on...

the Conclusion of 1,2 and 3 is we are not forced to judge! its not possible for us to know everything so when we reach "Doubt" we don't have to judge!

There is a Hadith from prophet Mohammad in Al-Kafi book (its one of the 4 main hadith books of Shia) [2]

> فمن ترك الشبهات نجا من المحرمات ومن أخذ بالشبهات ارتكب المحرمات وهلك
>   من حيث لا يعلم.

EN Translation:

> So Who leave doubts will be saved form Harams(Sins) and who take
>   doubts will do haram and will perish from something he can't think
>   about.

so next time we reach a point that we think there is a conflict between our religion and science, we simply do following:

***we ask Allah to help us, then we Search on the topic, research and ask professionals and if we don't satisfied and conflict didn't solved, we just leave it! and simply say I don't know! may God show me the truth...***

*Description & References*:

1. in Shia (My) and part of Sunni believe Imam Mahdi is alive but we don't know where is he.
   The Other Sunni's (Most of today's) believe is he is not born yet.
2. الكافي - الشيخ الكليني - ج ١ - الصفحة ٦٨